# Не могу удалить визуальные компоненты программно.(разработка под android)

Tags: c++, c++builder, radstudio

Не могу удалить визуальные компоненты программно.(разработка под android)
программа radstudio c++builder;

```
delete Button1;
Button1->Free();
```

Работает только если компилировать под win32, под платформу android оно не удаляет.

Comment: Не очень знаю, о чем вы, но обращаться к указателю после его удаления?!! Это же UB в чистом виде...

Comment: это варианты которые я попробовал. Я их не вместе писал